# Browser display the image file sent from C server as a long string of characters

Tags: html, c, sockets, ftp

I have been working on creating a small C server to which browsers can connect and make "GET" requests for files. I ran the basic structure of the server using the typical "socket", "bind", "listen", and "accept". Then I used the file descriptor "accept" in order to invoke "write" or "send" calls to the client, which makes "GET" requests in the form of

```
    http://ip_address:port/request
```

The first step I took was reading from the accept_fd (returned by accept) and get the first line of it, which was "GET /request HTTP/1.1\r\n". Then I use this to create a proper HTTP headers to send files over.

```
    GET /image_file.gif HTTP/1.1\r\n
    \r\n
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
    Content-Type: image.gif\r\n
    Content-Length: 9184\r\n
    \r\n
```

The content length was fetched from the st_size of the file statistics and corresponds to the file I want to send over, so this tells me I am dealing with the right file. I use "fopen" with "r" for reading and store the content with "fread" into a big character array which I made. Then finally, I sent the buffer in which the content of the file is stored using "send" and the client browser receives it, but the contents displayed are some gibberish string of unrecognizable characters (possibly binary).

```
    GIF89awÄ��ëQiò‹›òŒ›øÅÍìRiæ&Cýðòîn‚õ¨´éC\úÓÙè4Pûâæó™§í`uð}Žö¶Àõ©
```

Here is a snippet of what it looks like on the browser instead of an image file. I have been trying to solve this problem for four days and tried various things like sending each part of the HTTP headers individually instead of sending it all at once, sending the image file one byte at a time using "fgetc" and "write" but none of these attempts succeeded. Is there something wrong with what I am doing to send an image file over? (and the html files too. when I try to send it over, all the tags appear as though it was a text file instead of the browser interpreting and formatting the page.)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STAT_200 " 200 OK\r\n"
#define STAT_404 " 404 Not Found\r\n"
#define STAT_501 " 501 Not Implemented\r\n"

#define F_DIR "Content-Type: text/directory\r\n"
#define F_GIF "Content-Type: image/gif\r\n"
#define F_HTML "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
#define F_JPEG "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
#define F_JPG "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n"
#define F_TXT "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"

typedef enum {cgi, gif, html, jpeg, jpg, plain} ext;

ext get_ext(char *file) {
    if (strstr(file, ".cgi") != NULL)
        return cgi;
    if (strstr(file, ".gif") != NULL)
        return gif;
    if (strstr(file, ".html") != NULL)
        return html;
    if (strstr(file, ".jpeg") != NULL)
        return jpeg;
    if (strstr(file, ".jpg") != NULL)
        return jpg;
    if (strstr(file, ".txt") != NULL)
        return plain;
}

void parse(int accept_fd) {
    char *response = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
    char *content = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
    if (read(accept_fd, content, 512) < 0) {
        perror("read error");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *part_end = strstr(content, "\n");
    *(part_end + 1) = 0;     // still has \r\n
    strcat(response, content);
    strcat(response, "\r\n");
    // send(accept_fd, content, strlen(content), MSG_CONFIRM);
    // send(accept_fd, "\r\n", 2, MSG_CONFIRM);     // empty line
    *(part_end - 1) = 0;     // no more \r\n

    char *type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);      // "GET"
    char *request = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);   // "/request"
    char *version = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);   // "HTTP/x.x"
    strcpy(type, content);
    strcpy(request, strstr(content, "/"));
    strcpy(version, strstr(content, "HTTP"));
    part_end = strstr(type, "/");
    *(part_end - 1) = 0;
    part_end = strstr(request, "HTTP");
    *(part_end - 1) = 0;

    strcat(response, version);
    // send(accept_fd, version, strlen(version), MSG_CONFIRM);     // write the "HTTP/x.x"

    if (strcmp(type, "GET") != 0) { // 501
        strcat(response, STAT_501);
        // send(accept_fd, STAT_501, strlen(STAT_501), MSG_CONFIRM);

    }

    struct stat f_stat;
    int stat_fd;
    char *cwd = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    char *f_name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    if ((cwd = getcwd(cwd, 256)) == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd error");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(f_name, cwd);
    strcat(f_name, request);

    if ((stat_fd = stat(f_name, &f_stat)) < 0) { // 404
        strcat(response, STAT_404);
        // send(accept_fd, STAT_404, strlen(STAT_404), MSG_CONFIRM);

    }

    if S_ISDIR(f_stat.st_mode) { // 200
        strcat(response, STAT_200);
        strcat(response, F_DIR);
        strcat(response, "\r\n"); 
        // send(accept_fd, STAT_200, strlen(STAT_200), MSG_CONFIRM);    // # stat
        // send(accept_fd, "Content-Type: text/directory\r\n", 30, MSG_CONFIRM);
        // send(accept_fd, "\r\n", 2, MSG_CONFIRM);
        write(accept_fd, response, strlen(response));

        int red;
        if ((red = dup2(accept_fd, STDOUT_FILENO)) < 0) {
            perror("dup error");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (execlp("ls", "ls", f_name, NULL) < 0) {
            perror("exec error");
            exit(1);
        }

        close(accept_fd);
        exit(0);
    } else if S_ISREG(f_stat.st_mode) { // 200
        strcat(response, STAT_200);
        // send(accept_fd, STAT_200, strlen(STAT_200), MSG_CONFIRM);    // # stat
        ext f_ext = get_ext(f_name);

        if (f_ext == cgi) {
            int red;
            if ((red = dup2(accept_fd, STDOUT_FILENO)) < 0) {
                perror("dup error");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (execlp(f_name, f_name, NULL) < 0) {
                perror("exec family error");
                exit(1);
            }

            close(accept_fd);
            exit(0);
        } else if (f_ext == gif) {
            strcat(response, F_GIF);
            // send(accept_fd, F_GIF, strlen(F_GIF), MSG_CONFIRM);

            FILE *f_open;
            char *f_cont = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 524288);
            size_t f_size = f_stat.st_size;
            char *con_len = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);

            sprintf(con_len, "Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n", (int) f_size);
            strcat(response, con_len);
            write(accept_fd, response, strlen(response));
            // send(accept_fd, con_len, strlen(con_len), MSG_CONFIRM);  // Content-length: #\r\n

            if ((f_open = fopen(f_name, "r")) == NULL) {
                perror("fopen error");
                exit(1);
            }

            // int i;
            // char ch;
            // for (i = 0; i < f_size; i++) {
            //     ch = fgetc(f_open);
            //     send(accept_fd, &ch, 1, MSG_CONFIRM);
            // }

            fread(f_cont, sizeof(char), f_size, f_open);
            send(accept_fd, f_cont, f_size, MSG_CONFIRM);
            close(accept_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
```

Here is the relevant part of the code, and I checked repeatedly whether I missed any \r or \n in the header by checking the string lengths, but no good. People who have experiences with this, can you note where the mistake is? Am I misusing any functions anywhere? I got rid of the part where it sends html files because it failed before so I was mainly working on transferring a gif file over.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser tools and checking the headers coming back? Your `GIF89...` output implies that the content-type header is not being passed back properly (check for following characters before the newline, etc).

Comment: Is there some bad encoding issue? `�`

Comment: @AdrianWragg How can I check it on the browser? The \r and \n characters do not appear on the browser so I tried checking it by printing the string lengths of each parts.

Comment: @JoDev Does that question mark represent an error? Can you suspect where that could be coming from? Improper use of functions?

Comment: For my part, I'm a PHP dev, and when i see this sort of chars, I directly wonder if it would not be an encoding issue... Bad `http headers`. I don't suspect anything precisely, because if it was the case, I would have post an answer instead of a comment... ^^ sorry! (just an idea, sometimes i use `base64 encoding` to send file stream to browsers)

Comment: @user3583419 Are you familiar with the browser debug tools? F12 in Chrome, Firebug on Firefox, F12 on Internet Explorer; all have a way of tracing the network traffic and viewing the HTTP headers directly. Also just noticed in your first sample, `Content-Type: image.gif` instead of `Content-Type: image/gif` - typo?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I tried using chrome and sending the file to the client and chrome somehow chooses to not display any header but downloads the received-image file directly. But when I open the downloaded file, it doesn't display anything because it "doesn't support the format". I was kind of expecting that I would be able to see escape sequences like "\r\n" displayed on F12 debugging screen, but it still doesn't display anything substantially different from what I would see on the browser page, except I have quotation marks around it. Does this seem to be a problem?

Comment: @user3583419 Can you confirm that you're looking at the `network` tab? If you have it open and click `refresh` you should be able to select the HTTP call and view the response headers.

Comment: @AdrianWragg thanks. I got it to work. It turns out the response from the server starts from the third line of what I thought was right. So if I sent it "HTTP/1.1 ..." it would work. Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianWragg Sorry, it's my first time using these features on this website. I was actually trying to figure out how to set a question "solved" when it does not have any answers provided. I guess I have to post an answer to this myself?

Comment: @user3583419 Yes - you'll then be able to accept it (I think you might have to wait 20 minutes or so before it'll let you do that, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the headers are supposed to start from the third line of what I thought was the correct header. So it should look like this:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
    Content-Type: text/html\r\n
    \r\n
    [file content]
```